# DFS with cyclic dependency

Tags: algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was attempting to solve [this challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/pacific-atlantic-water-flow/description/)

> Given an m x n matrix of non-negative integers representing the height
>   of each unit cell in a continent, the "Pacific ocean" touches the left
>   and top edges of the matrix and the "Atlantic ocean" touches the right
>   and bottom edges.
>
> Water can only flow in four directions (up, down, left, or right) from
>   a cell to another one with height equal or lower.
>
> Find the list of grid coordinates where water can flow to both the
>   Pacific and Atlantic ocean.
>
> Note: The order of returned grid coordinates does not matter. Both m
>   and n are less than 150.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
>  Given the following 5x5 matrix:
>
>    Pacific ~   ~   ~   ~   ~ 
>         ~  1   2   2   3  (5) *
>         ~  3   2   3  (4) (4) *
>         ~  2   4  (5)  3   1  *
>         ~ (6) (7)  1   4   5  *
>         ~ (5)  1   1   2   4  *
>            *   *   *   *   * Atlantic
>
>  Return:
>
>  [[0, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 2], [3, 0], [3, 1], [4, 0]] (positions
>  with parentheses in above matrix).
> ```

And this is my solution

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<pair<int, int>> result;
    map<pair<int, int>, pair<bool, bool>> dp;
    //    P     A
    pair<bool, bool> doPacific(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, vector<vector<bool>> & visited,  int row, int col)
    {
        cout << row << ' ' << col << endl;
        if(col < 0 || row < 0)
        {
            return pair<bool, bool>(true, false);
        }
        if(col >= matrix[0].size() || row >= matrix.size())
        {
            return pair<bool, bool>(false, true);
        }
        if(visited[row][col])
        {
            return dp[make_pair(row, col)];
        }
        pair<bool,bool> left(false, false);
        pair<bool,bool> right(false, false);
        pair<bool,bool> top(false, false);
        pair<bool,bool> bottom(false, false);
        visited[row][col] = true;
    // Go Down if index is invalid or has valid index and water level
    if(((row + 1 < matrix.size()) && (matrix[row + 1][col] <= matrix[row][col])) || row + 1 >= matrix.size())
    {
        bottom = doPacific(matrix,visited, row + 1, col);
    }
    if(((row - 1 >= 0) && (matrix[row - 1][col] <= matrix[row][col])) || (row -1 < 0))
    {
            top = doPacific(matrix,visited, row - 1, col);
    }
    if(((col + 1 < matrix[0].size()) && (matrix[row][col + 1] <= matrix[row][col])) || (col + 1>= matrix[0].size()))    
    {
            right = doPacific(matrix,visited, row, col + 1);
    }
    if(((col - 1 >=0) && (matrix[row][col - 1] <= matrix[row][col])) || (col -1 < 0))
    {
        left = doPacific(matrix,visited, row, col - 1);
    }

        pair<bool, bool>returnValue(false, false);

        returnValue.first |= left.first;
        returnValue.second |= left.second;

        returnValue.first |= right.first;
        returnValue.second |= right.second;

        returnValue.first |= bottom.first;
        returnValue.second |= bottom.second;

        returnValue.first |= top.first;
        returnValue.second |= top.second;

        dp.insert(make_pair(make_pair(row, col), returnValue));
        if(returnValue.first && returnValue.second)
        {
            result.push_back(make_pair(row, col));
        }
        return returnValue;

    }
    vector<pair<int, int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        vector<vector<bool>> visited(matrix.size(), vector<bool>(matrix[0].size(), false));
        result.clear();
        dp.clear();
        for(int i=0; i< matrix.size(); ++i)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < matrix[0].size(); ++j)
            {
                if(!visited[i][j])
                {
                    doPacific(matrix, visited, i, j); 
                }                
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

But my solution failed for input

```
[10,10,10]
[10, 1,10]
[10,10,10]
```

My answer only omitted the index `(0,1)`.

When I traced the recursion tree it looked something like this.

```
                    (0, 0)
                     /
                  (1,0)
                   /
               (2, 0)
                 /   \
            (2, 1)  (2, 2)
               /      /
         (T,F)/    (1,2)
          (1, 1)     /
                  (0,2)
                    /
                 (0,1) This return(T,F) when it should return (T,T).
                       Because (0,1) won't call (0,0) since it is 
                       already being processed(i.e visited) which in turn depends on (0,1), 
                       creating a cycle. Although there exists a path 
                       from (0,0) to atlantic
```

My question is how do I solve such a situation when there is a cyclic dependency between the existing node and the node to be added.

Is the approach to such problem incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think this question needs to be solved using DFS? I think simple memoization should work here.

Comment: what do represent the two `bool`s that `doPacific()` returns ?

Comment: @fjardon, what do you think is correct answer for the second sample that OP has posted? Won't it be all cells except (0,1) which OP's solution is already outputting (as he claims)?

Comment: @fjardon the `doPacific()` return a `pair<bool,bool>` representing if Pacific and/or Atlantic and be reached. After checking if either one of the direction is able to reach either Pacific/Atlantic return the new possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your implementation:

1. you only consider two states for a node: `not visited` and `visited`. But you can indeed fall in a third state. Usually we consider the colors `white`, `gray` and `black`. In your code the `gray` and `black` colors are merged together in a single `visited` state.
2. when entering a new node, if you marked the node as `visited` you don't visit it again but just lookup its value in your `dp` array. As you found yourself, it doesn't work because the `dp` array is correct only for `black` cells, not for `gray`cells. But because of problem 1. you cannot make the difference

The reason why your `dp` array is not correctly updated for `gray` cells is that you try to do two things at the same time:

1. compute if a cell is touched by Pacific
2. compute if a cell is touched by Atlantic

But with a single DFS you can update one property on the forward path, and the second only on the backward path of your traversal.

A solution is to update each property separately with two DFS.

Instead of a single DFS you could try to do two [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) starting from one ocean then the second. Each flood-fill is a DFS but from a different source, and upating a different `visited` property. Obviously, you reverse the condition for the flow, that is your *water* flows from lower to upper elevation.

After the two flood-fills you eventually output all cells touched by both oceans. Flood-fill is `O(n*m)` so it doesn't degrade the complexity compared to your current implementation.

In my implementation I start `n+m` flood fills for each ocean, but I keep the same `visiteds` maps, so it still remains in `O(n*m)`

Here is an example solution (readable but still faster than 91% of c++ submission). See that I use a bitmasking technique to mark the cells visited by oceans (1 -> pacific, 2 -> atlantic, 3 -> both) instead of a `pair<bool,bool>` but this is just for performance optimisation.

```cpp
int width, height;
vector<vector<unsigned char>> visiteds;

void floodFill(int i, int j, unsigned char mask, vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    visiteds[i][j] = visiteds[i][j] | mask;

    auto& h = matrix[i][j];

    if(i > 0 && matrix[i-1][j] >= h && !(visiteds[i-1][j] & mask))
        floodFill(i-1, j, mask, matrix);

    if(i < height-1 && matrix[i+1][j] >= h && !(visiteds[i+1][j] & mask))
        floodFill(i+1, j, mask, matrix);

    if(j > 0 && matrix[i][j-1] >= h && !(visiteds[i][j-1] & mask))
        floodFill(i, j-1, mask, matrix);

    if(j < width-1 && matrix[i][j+1] >= h && !(visiteds[i][j+1] & mask))
        floodFill(i, j+1, mask, matrix);
}

vector<pair<int, int>> pacificAtlantic(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    vector<pair<int,int>> cells;
    height = matrix.size();
    if(! height)
        return cells;

    width = matrix[0].size();
    visiteds.clear();
    visiteds.resize(height, vector<unsigned char>(width, 0));

    for(int k=0; k<height; ++k) {
        floodFill(k, 0, 1, matrix);
        floodFill(k, width-1, 2, matrix);
    }
    for(int k=0; k<width; ++k) {
        floodFill(0, k, 1, matrix);
        floodFill(height-1, k, 2, matrix);
    }

    for(size_t i=0; i<height; ++i)
        for(size_t j=0; j<width; ++j)
            if(visiteds[i][j] == 3)
                cells.push_back(make_pair(i, j));
    return cells;
}
```